# How to get the appropriate weekdays to show up?

Tags: r, date, strptime

I've inputted the following code:

```
exdata1$DateTime <- strptime(paste(exdata1$Date, exdata1$Time), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") 

library(lubridate)
summary(wday(exdata1$DateTime, label=TRUE))
```

and it gives me

```
 Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat NA's 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 2880
```

But it should be giving me 1440 for both Thursday and Friday.

How to improve?

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(exdata1))` ?

Comment: dput gives a lot of output... I don't think it's something I should be pasting here.

Comment: you should at least show the first few entries of `exdata1$Date` and `exdata1$Time` to understand the format of data that you have. It is difficult to debug without that.

Comment: > head(exdata1$Date)
[1] "2007-02-01" "2007-02-01" "2007-02-01" "2007-02-01" "2007-02-01" "2007-02-01"
> head(exdata1$Time)
[1] 00:00:00 00:01:00 00:02:00 00:03:00 00:04:00 00:05:00
1440 Levels: 00:00:00 00:01:00 00:02:00 00:03:00 00:04:00 00:05:00 00:06:00 00:07:00 00:08:00 00:09:00 00:10:00 00:11:00 00:12:00 00:13:00 00:14:00 ... 23:59:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong format. In base R you can try :

```
exdata1$DateTime <- strptime(paste(exdata1$Date, exdata1$Time), 
                             format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Can also use `as.POSIXct` instead of `strptime` and then use `weekdays` function

```
weekdays(exdata1$DateTime)
```

---

With `lubridate`, you can do

```
library(lubridate)

exdata1$DateTime <- ymd_hms(paste(exdata1$Date, exdata1$Time))
wday(exdata1$DateTime, label = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I had to shift the year month thing to what I had to the earlier in the assignment. So this was unexpected, if anything, a bit annoying that there are so many little things that needs to be taken care of in R.

Comment: yes, it can be confusing sometimes to decide which format to use hence, `lubridate` has functions which don't need you to remember formats.